# LGA775 motherboard & RTX 2070

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, nvidia-graphics-card

I have an ASRock G31M motherboard with Intel Core 2 Duo CPU installed on it. Recently I have ordered Gigabyte RTX 2070 graphic card and a PSU for it (Thermaltake Berlin 630W). I have installed it into motherboard and it works fine on bootsplashes, but after that signal disappears. I've tried Windows 7 and it loads successfully if only basic videoadapter driver is installed, but the problem begins after installing NVidia drivers. Windows 10 was able to be installed up to "preparing devices" after pointing some basic settings (language, username etc.) but signal also disappeared after that. Ubuntu 19.04 acts strange - just randomly freezes (but once I succeeded to notice a message "CPU#0 stuck for 23s!", dunno is it related or not). What can be the reason of such behavior?

Comment: Is it a new or a used card?

Comment: It's new, ordered from computeruniverse

Comment: Do you have the chance to put into another machine? If your screen goes dark after installing drivers it might be that your 2D is working fine but 3D is broken.

Comment: I've brought the card to service today. They have tested it and said that the card is completely functional.

Comment: You're trying to use a very new graphics card in a very old motherboard. Problems should be expected. I'm not sure that board supports the PCIe version required/expected by the Nvidia card.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia as far as I know PCIe should be downwards compatible, the card will just be (much) slower. There have been situations where a chipset had problems with a card (Original Ryzen chipset and some Elegato cards) but as he is able to use the card up until the point the driver is installed I find that unlikely.

Comment: @SniperJoe95 were those Windows installs fresh installs? Did you check that all connectors for the card are properly plugged in?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia  I was told the same at the service :D

Comment: @Seth Win 10 definitly was. Win 7 was not. 
I checked all the connectors and even re-plugged them many times to make sure.